# How to create a view controller file after creating a new view controller? (xcode 8.21)

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to develop a tabbed activity app in xcode 8.21, and it only starts you out with two tabs. I want to make a third tab. I followed an online tutorial by adding another view controller and linking it to the tab bar controller. However, it doesn't automatically create a ViewController.swift file. All the tutorials are out of date (already), so I tried manually creating a .swift file called ThirdViewController.swift. Then, in the custom class section of the view controller, I tried typing ThirdViewController but it didn't work. Please help, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Every tutorial I've seen online is already outdated.

Comment: Why is this tagged Objective-C while your question talks about creating a Swift file? Please fix accordingly.

Comment: Because I've seen in some tutorials that I can add an objective-c file in xcode.

Comment: And? Is your question about adding a Swift file or an Objective-C file for your view controller? If it's Swift, then tag with Swift and not Objective-C. If it's Objective-C, [edit] your question to talk about adding an Objective-C file instead of a Swift file.

Comment: Ok, I'll remove it from the tags then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chose the wrong path to generate your file. In Xcode select "Cocoa Touch Class" instead of "Swift File" you can then decide if you want a Swift or Objective-C file with a specific Class (UIViewController in this case)
[image: Xcode dialog new File]

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you so much!

Comment: If my answer really was the solution to your problem, please mark it accordingly on here. Other people might find this helpful as well in similar situations then.

Comment: Wait, how do I do that? Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Wait, that didn't solve the problem though. How do I link the view controller to the cocoa touch class?

Comment: Exactly the way you tried, open your Storyboard, click on the Controller -> "Identity Inspector" Tab -> "Custom Class". If it doesn't appear, you did not select the correct parent-class for your new file. It should show you which class is needed in grey under "Class".

Comment: Hm, I tried typing in ThirdViewController into that section but it didn't accept it

Comment: What kind of ViewController do you have in your storyboard and what kind of ViewController is your ThirdViewController?

Comment: Oh wait nevermind, it worked! I just had to delete the view that was already in the view controllers and then enter in ThirdViewController. Thanks!